# Can Detaching A Thread Lead To A Torn Write

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, parallel-processing, thread-safety

Good day,

I am new to threading, and I am wondering if I have something like (context of C++, and X threading library):

```
//Pseudo code...//
void OnThread() {
    someGlobalVar = 2;
    someGlobalVar += 4;
}
void main()
{
    ThreadHandle someThreadHandle = MakeThread( &OnThread );
    //Can a torn write occur?//
    someThreadHandle.Detach();
    //Can "someGlobalVar" be trusted?//
    std::cerr << someGlobalVar << "\n";
    return ( 0 );
}
```

Could `someGlobalVar` have a torn write applied to it, can it be considered "safe" after the detach?

Comment: The two threads potentially access `SomeGlobalVar` at the same time, at least one is performing a write - this is a data race. The program has undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is safe to detach a thread as long as your program is still running, The thread will keep running after you detach it. But it would be safer to use a join which will block until the thread is done executing.

Comment: What do you mean indefinitely?

Comment: I mean is there any possibility that, `someGlobalVar += 4;` will not execute but `someGlobalVar = 2;` will not?

Comment: if the program exits before the thread gets to `someGlobalVar = 2;`